# not able to install 'fable' package (ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fable’)

Tags: r, installation, package, fable-r

I am trying to install fable running the command install.packages("fable"), as it says in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fable/readme/README.html

however i am getting the following:

[image]

It says clearly that it is because i don't have llapack, lblas and lgfortran in my computer. But i am not sure how to procede here. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

I'll appreciate any guidence.

Comment: At the terminal (Bash or whatever, not R) execute something like `sudo apt-get install llapack` etc to install the missing programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install from sources, you will need a GNU Fortran compiler installed. On Ubuntu this can be done with `sudo apt install gfortran`.

Alternatively, you can install a precompiled binary from the RStudio Package Manager - some guidance on how this can be done can be found here: https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/client/#/repos/1/overview